# Why does this code need a second if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand why one version of code works and one does not. I hope I've included enough information. I'm taking it from a online tutorial that is no longer supported.

In the tutorial, the instructions say to write the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
    var input = $("#command_line").val();
    console.log(input)
    console.log("submit")

    if (input === "help") {
        $("#message_help").clone().insertBefore("placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
    }
});

$("#command_line").val("");

});
```

There are no error messages in the console, but what is expected to happen in the browser doesn't execute.

In the working code, there is another if statement above the original:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
    var input = $("#command_line").val();
    console.log(input);


    if (input.indexOf("help") > -1) {
        if (input == "help") {
            $("#message_help").clone().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        }
    }       
});

$("#command_line").val("");

});
```

Why does this need the second if statement using the indexOf on the string 'help'? I looked up indexOf, and understand what it does, but I would have thought they both do the same thing?

Comment: Why are you using if (input === "help") instead of if (input == "help") as shown in the working snippet?

Comment: can you make a fiddle? both look like they should work

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong, hence your facts are wrong. Unfortunately your code is too top secret for us to see an actual example so that's all I got.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a typo in the first example.  Look at this line in your second example:

```
$("#message_help").clone().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
```

You have `insertBefore("#placeholder")`, which looks up the element with the ID of "placeholder" and inserts the `clone` before it.

In your first example you've skipped the `#`, so it's looking for a TAG of "placeholder" (eg: `<placeholder>`) - which doesn't exist.  Hence the element will be successfully `clone`d, but will be inserted after *nothing*.

- `$('div')` will return all the `<div>`s on the page.
- `$('.pie')` will return all the elements on the page with a CLASS of "pie"
- `$('#pie')` will return the element on the page with an ID of "pie".

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It IS supposed to work. There's something definitely wrong with this line:

```
    $("#message_help").clone().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
```

Maybe `#placeholder` or `#message_help` or both don't exist.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcxwk771/1/)